# Are these two bounds close to each other?

Tags: functions

Recently I proved a some bound about something. The bound is 
(details : come soon)

Upper bound $f(k)< k^{k^{O(k)}}$.

Lower bound $f(k)< k^{k^2-o(k)}$

---

My question is

1. Are these two bounds close? For general meaning.
2. What should I call the lower bound? An exponential function? Or something other looks like a litter larger. Clearly it is not as large as double exponential.
3. Should I need to stress that the exponent in the lower bound is $k^2$.

Answer (score 1):

For large, and even medium-sized $k$, the upper bound is hugely bigger than the lower bound. But for $k$ not too large, the two bounds might be not far from  each other if the implied constant in the $O(k)$ is very close to $0$.

The $O(k)$ means that for the upper bound, all we know is that the exponent of $k$ is, for large $k$, less than $k^{ck}$ for some constant $c$.  The lower bound is not quite put in lower bound language: a lower bound means a floor below which a function does not go, so I assume that what is meant is $f(k)\gt k^{k^2-o(k)}$. Thus the exponent of $k$ is of size roughly $k^2$.

So already for the upper bound, the **exponent** of $k$ is a fast growing function, while the exponent in the lower bound grows relatively slowly.

In each case, exponentiating results in very fast growing functions. However, the upper bound grows enormously faster.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer。I really need the “for large” answer。